# How to assign multiple interface to variable

Tags: typescript

When I tried the below code:

```
export interface Iexpand {
  isTitle: boolean;
  isChart: boolean;
}

public expand:Iexpand | boolean =  {
    isTitle: false,
    isChart: true,
  }
```

In class block, when I tried to use:

```
expand?.isChart = .....
```

It is giving me this error:

```
Property 'isChart' does not exist on type 'boolean | Iexpand '.
  Property 'isChart' does not exist on type 'false'.
```

How to deal with this, where 'expand' can be object of interface 'Iexpand' or a boolean value?

Comment: What _should_ happen if it's a boolean?!

Comment: expand = true/false

Comment: Yes, and how precisely did you think `expand?.isFilters` would deal with that possibility? TypeScript is telling you the right thing: your code is unsafe.

Comment: Can't we define multiple interface to single variable in typeScript ?

Comment: Yes. That's working fine. Then the compiler can tell you whether the code consuming that variable makes sense, which yours does not.

Comment: That's not the expected solution needed here @jonrsharpe

Comment: It's unclear what you _want_ to happen. Either you shouldn't say the variable could have a boolean value, or you should deal with the possibility that it could.

Comment: What should `expand = true; expand.isTitle = true;` do? What does `true.isTitle` mean?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with [tag:angular], and [tag:interface] is a pointless meta tag.

Comment: You need to assert that `expand` is the correct type before doing stuff with it. `if(typeof expand==="boolean"){ /* expand is boolean*/}else{/* expand is {isTitle: boolean; isChart: boolean;}*/}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `expand` can be either an `Iexpand` or `boolean`. That can lead to an undefined situation if you were to call `<boolean>.isChart`. The `?` operator only makes sense in the case that `expand` were potentially `undefined`, but it isn't marked as optional ever.

To resolve your situation, first you may want to consider whether your types make sense. Perhaps you want `expand` to be `Iexpand | undefined` instead? Generally, having a variable be both a primitive and an object is probably going to be a problem.

One alternative is checking the type of your variable before doing an option:

```js
if (typeof expand !== 'boolean') {
  expand.isChart = ...
}
```

But you may also want to look out for better ways in order to ensure your code is type-safe.